# GetFileAttributes returns FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY for invalid input

Tags: c++, winapi

I am puzzled with the behavior of this piece of code.

```
const char* file_name = "/  /";
auto attributes = GetFileAttributes(TEXT(file_name)); // same result without TEXT macro
if (attributes == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
{
  //error
}
else if (attributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
{
  //directory
}
```

This is invalid name for a file or a directory, so I would expect this to return INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES. 
Compiled with VS2015 running on win8.
Maybe this is because of a forward char? And maybe there is a winAPI function to validate the input?

thanks

Comment: It returns `-1` for me (failure).

Comment: ANSI or Unicode? Is there a reason why you use the TEXT macro? Surely you can stick to Unicode.

Comment: *"This is invalid name for a file or a directory"* - Why? Looks like a perfectly valid directory name to me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no particular reason, same behavior without TEXT macro.

Comment: @IInspectable it is not valid name, as / (forward slash) is reserved character: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Tadzys: From the link you posted ([Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx)): *"File I/O functions in the Windows API convert "/" to "\" as part of converting the name to an NT-style name, except when using the "\\?\" prefix as detailed in the following sections."*

Comment: `GetFileAttributes` takes a relative path; the Win32 API also allows `/` as a path separator. What you have is a valid name: you're asking about a directory on the root of the current drive with a bunch of spaces as the name.

Comment: @IInspectable ah yes, you are right! thanks!

Comment: `TEXT(file_name)` is not valid code, it should not even compile. `TEXT()` can only be used with compile-time literals, which `file_name` is not. And `(attributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)` should be `(attributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)` as other flags may also be present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"/  /"` is a perfectly valid filename. The forward slash `/` is interpreted as a path separator.

Therefore, on the basis that we trust the system, the logical conclusion is that there is a directory named `"  "` at the root level of the current working volume on the machine where you run this code.

Comment: In other words, apply Occam's razor

Comment: Oh crap, indeed, I missed the bit where forward slash was interpreted as path separator. (and my other test has created directory with spaces). Thanks for your help!